# php str_replace with regular expression

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have some text that i need to delete fron code and i using much variants like this:

```
$answer = str_replace('<td style="background-color:#80F9CC;">', '', $answer);
$answer = str_replace('<td style="background-color:#E1E3E4;">', '', $answer);
$answer = str_replace('<td style="background-color:#D1D3D4;">', '', $answer);
$answer = str_replace('<td style="background-color:#73F6AB;">', '', $answer);
$answer = str_replace('<td style="background-color:#3CEB88;">', '', $answer);
```

Is there way to create one str_replace function that will delete this text with some regular expression?

Comment: Im just wondering about your end goal here.. if you replace your opening `<td>` with a blank `''` then you are left with a close `</td>` tag without its opening tag, leading to bad HTML. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the function you need.

Assuming you want to identify and replace the hex representations of colors, the code is something along the lines:

```
$answer = preg_replace('/<td style="background-color:#[0-9A-F]{6};">/i', '', $answer);
```

The [`i` PCRE modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) tells `preg_replace` to ignore character cases.

It identifies and replaces only when the color code contains exactly 6 hex digits. In order to make it identify color codes using the [3-digit RGB notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color) you need to change the `[0-9A-F]{6}` part of the `regexp` to `[0-9A-F]{3}([0-9A-F]{3})?`. Or use a simpler expression that matches all color codes between 3 and 6 digits: `[0-9A-F]{3,6}`

You could also put `\s*` after the colon (`:`) to make it also match when one or more whitespaces are present after the `background-color:` part.

The updated code is:

```
$answer = preg_replace(
    '/<td style="background-color:\s*#[0-9A-F]{3,6};">/i', '', $answer
);
```

However, if you want to match only some colors then you can put the color codes separated by `|` instead:

```
$answer = preg_replace(
    '/<td style="background-color:\s*#(80F9CC|E1E3E4|D1D3D4|73F6AB|3CEB88);">/i',
    '',
    $answer
);
```

Short explanation of the regular expression pieces:

```
<td style="background-color:    # plain text, matches if exact
\s*                             # matches zero or more (*) space characters (\s)
#                               # plain text, matches exactly one '#'
(                               # start of a group, doesn't match anything
     80F9CC                         # matches '80F9CC'
    |E1E3E4                         # or (|) 'E1E3E4'
    |D1D3D4                         # or 'D1D3D4'
    |73F6AB                         # or ...
    |3CEB88                         # or ...
)                               # end of the group    
;">                             # plain text; matches exactly this text
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution:)

Comment: Does this match the specific colors he has? or is it all colors with 6/3 digits?

Comment: It matches all the colors.

Comment: Gotcha, so I guess this would work perfectly if you want to remove all colors from the attributes, but not specific colors.

Comment: Now its perfect. Awesome breakdown.

Answer (score 3):

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can take an array as an argument:

```
$replace_array = [
    '<td style="background-color:#80F9CC;">',
    '<td style="background-color:#E1E3E4;">',
    '<td style="background-color:#73F6AB;">',
    '<td style="background-color:#3CEB88;">',
];

$answer = str_replace($replace_array, '', $answer);
```

or you could use a [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead